# Can I sync my AirPods 24 hours?

Tags: iphone, airpods

Sometimes I lose my AirPods and I can't find them. Is there a way to sync them constantly to avoid losing them, even while them aren't near the iPhone?

Comment: I've never used this product but it is designed to help you find misplaced items, there are others like it out there too. https://www.thetileapp.com/

Comment: Sync them with... what?  They don't have cellular radios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think you can because AirPods are online only while them are connected to your iPhone, so inconvenient